# Algorithm for finding population for a given center point and radius in US

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm

Here is what I have

1. The population data aggregated by zip code given by US Census.

Here is what I am doing right now:

1. Reverse geo code the center point to find the zip code of the center
   point.
2. Associate a lat-long to each zip-code(by reverse geocoding, I know
   this will be error prone).
3. Find the lat-longs(zip-codes) which are inside the circle, using
   Geokit-Rails plugin.
4. Finding the sum of the data for those zip-codes(zip-code=zipcode of the center point or distance(between lat-long of the zip code and center point) < radius) and showing.

Am I doing this right? Is there methods efficient than this to find the population? Is there any algorithm already available?

I am using geokit-rails plugin for reverse geocoding and for finding the zip-codes(with associated lat-longs) within the circle.

Comment: Offhand it sounds like you're on the right path. Do you feel like there is anything obvious to optimize, or are you looking for any sort of improvement in particular?  Short of writing the SQL query yourself, I can't imagine there's a faster way to get the data out of the database, and you'd probably end up writing the same query as geokit. It sounds like your lookup of the initial zipcode is pretty straightforward. I don't know of any better data sources.

Comment: I suggest using the google maps api to get the lat & long values for each zip code, rather than calculating it out. Here's a ruby script i used for calculating the 5 closest lat and long values to each one. It was essentially for linking the 5 closest cities in our list for each city: gist.github.com/1321520. The first couple methods there should help you out a bit. It returns the distance in kilometers. So convert it to miles to check if it's under 100. Here's an article explaining the formula: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: @agmcleod..I am using geokit-rails plugin to get lat-long for each zip-code..I believe geokit-rails plugin internally uses google map API(But google maps API has some restrictions on number of conversions for an user per day, so it uses other datasources also in case Google map API is not available)..I have set up a database with all zip codes and their corresponding lat-long found from the geokit-rails plugin. This is my initial setup. So, I am not calculating it out, it is already in the database.

Comment: @muffinista..The problem with this setup is that the zipcodes cannot be actually represented by the lat-long,it is an area.So, I am not sure the lat-long pair given by Google Map API is actually lies in the center of the zip code or something like that. Also,for radius 0 to almost 2.4 miles radius,the population remains same with this setup. That is, even for a radius of 0.1 miles, it will show the whole population of the zip code.I am looking for a way to approximate this..

Comment: @muffinista..but with my data,I will not be able to do this as I am not aware of the geographic location of the zip code.so,i am looking for better options.I am not looking for optimising my query or response time.I am just looking for better options.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a solution, but i think part of your problem lies in the concept of your algorithm itself.

You're trying to get an information that your data cannot give you accurately, because its granularity (scale) is not adapted. In this case, you're using a Centroid point that stands for an area, but is certainly not an accurate representation of the population's spatial distribution. It's like trying to measure millimeters with a ruler that only has centimeters marks...

One thing you can do to approximate the pop. is to create a **regular grid of points**, that *interpolates* your population data on a *finer granularity* (each point of the grid will get its share of its ZIP area population). This is a totally different, GIS-related question, so i would advise you to seek help among the [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) community.